# <s:DropDownList selectedItem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, air

I'd to use my database field value to select a value on my `<s:DropDownList`

I try to do

```
<s:DropDownList  dataProvider="{DP_PAT_CIVIL}" selectedItem="@{objectUser.usrQualParent}"/>
```

But no selection appear, nothing appear on prompt.

objectUser.usrQualParent represent a value with is present in the dataprovider `DP_PAT_CIVIL`.

For exemple, dataprovider is:

```
[Bindable]
        private var DP_PAT_CIVIL:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection (
            [{label:"Monsieur" , data:"0"},
            {label:"Madame", data:"1"},
            {label:"Mademoiselle", data:"2"},
            {label:"Le Jeune", data:"3"}]

            );
```

And `objectUser.usrQualParent` value is `"Monsieur"`.

Thanks for helping

Comment: nothing appear in the dropdownlist or in prompt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selected item should point to exact item from data provider. For simple types of which data provider can consist (like `String`, `Boolean` or `int`) it can be equal that value. For complex objects it should be exactly the same value (pointer to the same memory's unit).

So, in your case, `"Monsieur"` isn't an item of data provider which consists of `Object`s but not `String`s. But the following isn't the way too:

```
<s:DropDownList  dataProvider="{DP_PAT_CIVIL}" selectedItem="{{label:"Monsieur" , data:"0"}}"/>
```

because of it is newly created but not the same object.

I recommend you create some function for searching exactly the same value from the existing data provider using your string as a key:

```
private function getSelectedItem(dp:ArrayCollection, key:String):Object
{
    if (dp && dp.length > 0)
    {
        for each (var item:Object in dp)
        {
            if (item.label == key)
                return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now your list:

```
<s:DropDownList  dataProvider="{DP_PAT_CIVIL}" 
    selectedItem="{getSelectedItem(DP_PAT_CIVIL, objectUser.usrQualParent)}" 
    change="objectUser.usrQualParent = event.currentTarget.selectedItem.label"/>
```